# Am I breaking down this string correctly in C# .Net logic?

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading

Question: Assume integer variables x=10, y=5, z=3, w=2. The value of x+y%w is?

Possible answers: A: 11  B: 1 C: 12 D: none of the above

X+Y simple concatenation or addition operator with % which is remainder operator. Would this not be 10 + 5 =15 with a remainder 2? or 10 + 5 with a remainder of two?

Comment: Are these operators not specific to C#? It is for a C# .net specific class.

Comment: This also has nothing to do with strings.

Comment: Yea I see that now. Not sure what I was thinking when I said string, still a noob forsure. But can anyone explain how this is not specific to C#. There is even a C# operators page here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

% operator basically means divide and only use the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

```
x+y%w -> 10+5%2 = 11  because 5%2 (=1) has the highest priority
(x+y)%w -> (10+5)%2 = 1 because the parenthesis modify the priority of operator
```

Comment: I see. At first I did not realize the % operator basically means divide and get the remained. But now I understand thanks!

Comment: could you validate the answer please?

Comment: What about something like this  The value of (x++ + --y) - (++x + y--) is? Apparently the answer is -2 and I should be able to get this using order of operations and basic math but they never give us what x or y equals..

Comment: (x++ + --y) -> y = y - 1 then (x= 10) + (y=4) = 14 after the addition x = x + 1 (11)                      
//////// (++x + y--) -> x = x + 1  then (x = 12) + (y=4) = 16 after the operation y = y +1 but no deal  with the substration   result final 14 - 16 = 2

Comment: ++x the incrementation is done before the op and for x++ the incrementation is done after the operation